# check my explaination (explain why $(a,b)R(x,y)$ iff $a \leq x$ and $b \leq y$ is not toal order)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Im unsure whether I have the correct answer here, can someone please verify

consider the relation $R$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $(a,b)R(x,y)$ iff $a \leq x$ and $b \leq y$.

**explain why this is not a total order relation:**

a total order relation is partial order and has the property that any pair of elements $(a,b),(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}$ are related to each other in the form $(a,b),(x,y)\in R$ or $(x,y),(a,b)\in R$

this relation is not total order because there exists a pair of elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$ eg. $(-1,-2),(-3,-4)$, this pair of elements cannot be related because $-1 \nleq -3$ and $-2 \nleq -4$ and the relation is anti symmetric which doesnt allow $(-3,-4),(-1,-2)$ to occur

Comment: But $-3\le-1$ and $-4\le-2,$ right? Doesn't that mean that $(-3,-4)R(-1,-2)?$

Comment: Does $(1,2)R(2,1)$  hold? Does $(2,1)R(1,2)$ hold?

Comment: @bof thanks! that example is so obvious, i always miss the obvious things